# A subset of 3 dimensional matrix in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, submatrix

Lets assume we have a 3 dimensional matrix `A` and `X_IND = 4:8` and `Y_IND = f(X_IND)`.
`f` is a function like `2*x^2+1`. How I can extract following vector out of `A`:

```
a = A(X_IND,Y_IND,3)
```

However, above equation in MATLAB leads to a matrix while the result should be an array since `Y_IND` is function of `X_IND`.

Comment: You're indexing `A` as a 3D matrix, so obviously it will output a matrix. Please include the desired result of how `a` should look.

Comment: output = f(X_IND) = A(X_IND, corresponding Y(X_IND))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sub2ind`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to build a [linear index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/). Here's an example:

```
>> A = randi(9,2,3,3)
A(:,:,1) =
     6     8     8
     5     2     7
A(:,:,2) =
     8     7     9
     8     7     2
A(:,:,3) =
     8     9     8
     2     4     8

>> X_IND = [1 2]; 
>> Y_IND = X_IND + 1;
>> Z_IND = 3;

>> Z_IND = repmat(3, size(X_IND)); %// all indices should have the same size

>> ind = sub2ind(size(A), X_IND, Y_IND, Z_IND); %// build linear index

>> A(ind)
ans =
     9     8
```